# Debian 11 LXC Container - Not all packages from "apt" avaible

Tags: debian, lxc, linux-containers, proxmox, phpldapadmin

I have a proxmox installation and created a Debian 11 lxc container to install an LDAP server.

I want to install "phpldapadmin" with "apt install phpldapadmin". Error: Could not find the package.

In a normal Debian 11 VM, I can install it via "apt install phpladpadmin" without an error.

Have anywhere a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, in a new lxc container, you need to run `apt update` to get the package lists before you can install any packages.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install phpldapadmin
```

seems to work.